# positioning in html and css not working properly

Tags: html, css

Hi I am trying to get a list of images placed one below other and  on top of each image there is some text. I thought of this layout. I have a main `wrapper` with relative positioning which contains a `img-txt` div this also has relative positioning. and then this contains two divs one for image and other for text. But my images are stacked on top of each other why?

```css
    .wrapper{
      position:relative;
    }
    .img-txt{
      position: relative;
    }
    .iimg{
      position: absolute;
    }
    .text{
      position: absolute;
    }
```

```html
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="img-txt">
          <div class="iimg">
            <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/rMcW62wx1Qk/mqdefault.jpg"/>
          </div>
          <div class = "text">Test</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="img-txt">
          <div class="iimg">
            <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/rMcW62wx1Qk/mqdefault.jpg"/>
          </div>
          <div class = "text">Test</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="img-txt">
          <div class="iimg">
            <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/rMcW62wx1Qk/mqdefault.jpg"/>
          </div>
          <div class = "text">Test</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="img-txt">
          <div class="iimg">
            <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/rMcW62wx1Qk/mqdefault.jpg"/>
          </div>
          <div class = "text">Test</div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Edit : The text should be centered horizontally and vertically

Comment: like this https://jsfiddle.net/3cqx9oLs/

Comment: or like this https://jsfiddle.net/3cqx9oLs/1/

Comment: First of all, your structure is all wrong. What you have is a list of images. Use a list. Then set a `position: relative;` on the `<li>` of that list, and use some sort of container for the text inside (`<span>` springs to mind), and position that with `position: absolute;`

Comment: @Leothelion second one but text should be on top of images .basically what i want is to have a div of same size as image with some text on it .and when i hover over images div with text pops up. texts are to be centered. if you can show how this can be done

Comment: And I repeat, the structure is wrong - use proper markup, no a bunch of `<div>`s.

Comment: this iwas just a sample code to understand positioning with css for the code that i am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your `.iimg` to `position:relative;` and add `z-index` to the text. you can adjust text's position using `top` and `left`

```css
.wrapper{
      width:400px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border:1px solid black;
    }
    .img-txt{
      position: relative;
      width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
    }
    .iimg{
      position:relative;
      width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
    }
.iimg img{
      width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
      display:block;
    }
    .text{
      position: absolute;
      top:50%;
      left:50%;
      z-index:10;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="img-txt">
          <div class="iimg">
            <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/rMcW62wx1Qk/mqdefault.jpg"/>
          </div>
          <div class = "text">Test</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="img-txt">
          <div class="iimg">
            <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/rMcW62wx1Qk/mqdefault.jpg"/>
          </div>
          <div class = "text">Test</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="img-txt">
          <div class="iimg">
            <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/rMcW62wx1Qk/mqdefault.jpg"/>
          </div>
          <div class = "text">Test</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="img-txt">
          <div class="iimg">
            <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/rMcW62wx1Qk/mqdefault.jpg"/>
          </div>
          <div class = "text">Test</div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot but text should be vertically and horizontally centered

Comment: Then say that when you ask the question.

Comment: ok. I updated it. is it good? If it is can you please accept the answer. if not let me know

Comment: Yeah perfect .just a little explanation to why the first div was made relative would be immensely helpful

Comment: it's not necessary. I thought you had any other use for that . so I kept it

Comment: Now I removed it and see. it's still working perfect

Answer (score 1):

Here. Proper markup, and CSS.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  }
li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  }
li span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 100;
  visibility: hidden;
  }
li:hover span,img:hover ~ span {
visibility: visible;
  }
```

```html
<ul class="wrapper">
   <li>
      <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/rMcW62wx1Qk/mqdefault.jpg">
     <span>Test</span>
   </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/rMcW62wx1Qk/mqdefault.jpg">
    <span>Test</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/rMcW62wx1Qk/mqdefault.jpg">
    <span>Test</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/rMcW62wx1Qk/mqdefault.jpg">
    <span>Test</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. how can we center the texts (both way) .see edit

Comment: It is centered - see the updated version. Centered (vertically/horisontally) and with hover-effect.

Comment: Eh, yes it is. What browser are you using?

Comment: i am using chrome browser

Comment: Sorry, saw the problem now when I tested anew, updated the answer. Now it works fine in both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131411/discussion-between-anekix-and-junkfoodjunkie).

Answer (score 0):

You can use min height if you know the height of the images but not for images with unknown heights

`.wrapper{
  min-height: 300px;
}`